# How to create a value not a list

Tags: r

I have this code:

```
m = sapply(split(DB, DB$ID), function(grp){
grp[max(grp$Time, na.rm =T), "Score"]-
grp[min(grp$Time, na.rm=T), "Score"]
})
```

Basically a code to calculate difference in score variables between rows (I have long data of repeated measures).
I want to get the m as a value not as a list because I want to merge it back in the database
how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `group_by` operation

```
library(dplyr)
DB %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(Score2 = Score[max(Time, na.rm = TRUE)] - 
       Score[min(Time, na.rm = TRUE)], .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: I am doing this code but I keep keeping datafame with score variable with only one observation and one value

Comment: @SariKatish then, change the mutate to summarise (updated)

Comment: I have no idea but this code isn't working for me, it just gives me score column and all the results are the same

Comment: @SariKatish try with `max/min` instead of `which.max/which.min` (based on your code).  Also, use `dplyr::summarise`

Comment: Unfortuntaely the code still not working for me
I am getting the same value in the score rather than different scores

Comment: @SariKatish have you used `dplyr::summarise` instedad of just `summarise`.  I believe it must be due to the masking of summarise from plyr